# org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager not found

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, compilation

I have a JSP file, I'm trying to compile it.
I'm getting below error 
 **org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager not found**

Am i missing any?

Comment: Could you post a large part of the stacktrace? When do you see this stacktrace? While starting Tomcat or while precompiling the JSPs?

Comment: IntfDetails_jsp.java:36: package org.apache.tomcat does not exist
  private org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager _jsp_instancemanager;
                           ^
IntfDetails_jsp.java:44: cannot access org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManag
er
class file for org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager not found
    _jsp_instancemanager = org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFa
ctory.getInstanceManager(getServletConfig());

                        ^
2 errors

Comment: Am trying to compile my jsp manually.